# button not displaying views

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have added multiple actions to one button

1. Play audiofile
2. Display array of views

Button is playing audiofile but not displaying views.

```
UIButton *playpauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[playpauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayviewsAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

playpauseButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);

[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[playpauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

UIBarButtonItem *playpause = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:playpauseButton];
```

Play Pause Action coding

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{

if  

  ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      [audioPlayer pause];

  } else {

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      [audioPlayer play];

  }  

}
```

DisplayviewsAction coding

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{

CGRect pageViewRect = self.view.bounds;

pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect, 30.0, 30.0);

self.pageViewController.view.frame = pageViewRect;

// Configure the page view controller 
   UIPageViewController *pageViewController = [[[UIPageViewController alloc]   initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil]autorelease];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:pageViewController]; 

[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers
direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
animated:NO
completion:nil];

[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

}
```

Any advice what i m missing in the code or doing wrong.

Thanks for help.

Comment: First off, you should make sure everything is initialized. Using `NSLog(@"%@", pageViewController);` may also help. The second thing you should do is make sure `pageViewController` has a view. Sometimes when these things are done in Xcode, they get a little picky. The most likely thing, however, is that `displayviewsAction` is not even being called. An `NSLog` should make sure you know if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some minor corrections you should make - they may not all help with the problem, but you never know.

Add a completion block here:

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers
direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
animated:NO
completion:nil];
```

I don't remember for sure, but I think `setViewControllers` is done asynchronously - nothing cannot be added until after the completion handler is done. To add the block, you simply put a `^` and a block of code in (like a normal method):

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers
direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
animated:NO
completion:^{
   // your code here.
}];
```

This may fix the problem, but I cannot be sure until I can get back to my computer.

You should also put an `NSLog` at the beginning of every method, at least until you are done debugging. That way, you always know what is being called and what isn't. If it is not called, try removing the `autorelease` from the `pageViewController` - it may be released because it isn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in displayviewsAction, try something more simple like:

```
- (void) displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
    UIView* testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 30.0, 30.0)];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:testView];
    [testView release];
}
```

That should help you narrow down the problem. Depending on what your final aim is you might not need all those view controllers; instead consider UIView's [transitionFromView...](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW113) for the animation effects.